# how to iterate a dictionary<string,string> in reverse order(from last to first) in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have one Dictionary and added some elements on it.for example,

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

d.Add("Content","Level0");
d.Add("gdlh","Level1");
d.Add("shows","Level2");
d.Add("ytye","Level0");
```

In C#, Dictionary keeps elements in natural order.But i now want to iterate those values from last to first(ie, Reverse order).i mean,

first i want to read ytye then shows,gdlh and finally Content.

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: You state *"In C#, Dictionary keeps elements in natural order"*. That is not correct. [The remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) states *"The order in which the items are returned is undefined."*

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth That was my initial thought, and I commented as such, but removed it because I tested some code and it works.  So I did a bit more research.  Ultimately it's possible for elements to reorder during insertion if it forces the dictionary to resize.  SortedDictionary is referring to the order of the keys, but you can give it a comparer … OrderedDictionary is non-generic, but may be what he needs.

Comment: I got into a huge argument once about this - while the "order" of enumerated entries in a standard Dictionary *is* basically the order you put them in, THIS IS NOT GUARANTEED BEHAVIOR! It is extremely unwise to assume this will always be the case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use the Linq extension method [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)

e.g.

```
foreach( var item in d.Reverse())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use LINQ Reverse, but note that does not *reverse in place*:

```
var reversed = d.Reverse();
```

But note that this is not a *SortedDictionary*, so the order is not necessarily guaranteed in the first place. Perhaps you want `OrderByDescending` instead?

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the order in a dictionary is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe `OrderByDescending` on the key. Like this:

```
d.OrderByDescending (x =>x.Key)
```

`Foreach` like this:

```
foreach (var element in d.OrderByDescending (x =>x.Key))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's available with Linq: `d.Reverse()`